# IBM Cloud Object Storage - can the order be made using API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

Is it possible for customers to make IBM ’could-object-storage' orders via API? It will be great if related guidance or samples can be provided. Ordering IBM Cloud Object Storage is described in [knowlegelayer](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/order-ibm-cos-s3), but it seems that there is not any info about doing it via API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can read more information here [Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs)

Currently, SoftLayer Control portal uses package 206 to order could-object-storage S3 and SWIFT types. To know the item prices you can perform following REST call.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getItemPrices
```

Use the service [SoftLayer_Product_Order::verifyOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder) to verify the order and use [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) when you ready to order.

**Order a S3 object storage type**

You need to send a [SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Object](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Object) object as following:

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: POST

Body:    
{
    "parameters" : [
            {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Object",
                "quantity": 1,
                "packageId": 206,
                "prices": [ { "id": 1111111 }]
            }
        ]
}
```

**Note:** Change **[userName]**, **[apiKey]**, and **111111** with your own data. Replace  **verifyOrder** by **placeOrder** when you ready to order.

**Order a SWIFT object storage**

On this case you need to send a [SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub) object. Following is an example:

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: POST

Body:
{
    "parameters" : [
            {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub",
                "quantity": 1,
                "packageId": 206,
                "prices": [ { "id": 222222 }]
            }
        ]
}
```

**Note:** Change **[userName]**, **[apiKey]**, and **222222** with your own data. Replace  **verifyOrder** by **placeOrder** when you ready to order.

I hope this help you.